# Any simplification of this inequality if it is true? :For $t\geq 1.22$: $|\zeta(0.5+it)|\leq 0.5 \frac{|\Gamma(0.5+it)|}{|\Gamma(-0.5+it)|}$

Tags: riemann-zeta-function, gamma-function, prime-number-theorem, lower-bounds, alternative-proof

When I tried to give bounds for $\zeta(0.5+it)$ using some transformations  over Gamma function using the function $f(x)=\exp(-n x)$  over the range $(0,+\infty)$ , For $ Re(s)=\frac12 $ and $t >0$ I come up to the final Bounds for  $\zeta(0.5+it) $ which is represented by the following formual :For $t\geq 1.22$: $$|\zeta(0.5+it)|\leq 0.5 \frac{|\Gamma(0.5+it)|}{|\Gamma(-0.5+it)|}\tag{1}$$, For Bounds of $\Gamma(s)$ it is found that is monotonic increasing function for $|t|\geq 5/4$ with the respect to the the real part of $s$ and it were false with  $|t|\leq 1$ in [this paper](http://web.math.ku.dk/~henrikp/cb/Gopala.pdf) entitled **On the Horizontal Monotonicity of $|\Gamma(s)|$** by **Gopala Krishna Srinivasan and P. Zvengrowski**, |$\Gamma(s)$| is given in the introduction  of that paper for $s=\sigma+ i t$ by this formula :
  $|\Gamma(\sigma+ i t)|=\lambda \frac{\Gamma(1+\sigma)}{\sqrt{\sigma^2+t^2}}\sqrt{\frac{2\pi t}{\exp(\pi t)-\exp(-\pi t)}},\lambda 
 \in(1,1+\sqrt{1+t^2})\tag{2}$, it seem the Right hand side of that formual related to cos hyperbolic function , Now When I tried to plug this formual in the RHS of my bounds it give me a complicated form such that no simple formula for simplification , My question here How I can simplify RHS OF $1$ if it is true ?

**Note:** The motivation of this question is to look for some connections of primes distribution to Gaussian distribution.

Comment: It should be noted that in (2) the $\lambda$ on the RHS is not a constant, but rather depends on $t$.

Comment: @Wojowu , Thanks for your attention, you are right ,$\lambda 
 \in(1,\sqrt{1+t^2})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHS of (1) is $\sim |t|$ by Stirling's formula.  The Weyl bound states that there exists a constant $c>0$ (which one can compute, but I won't) such that if $t\in\mathbb{R}$, then $|\zeta(\frac{1}{2}+it)|\leq c(|t|+1)^{1/6}$.  One can do better under assuming the Riemann hypothesis, see [Chandee and Soundararajan](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.2008).

Comment: You don't need Stirling's formula. For $z=-0.5+it$ the RHS is $0.5\frac{|\Gamma(z+1)|}{|\Gamma(z)|}=0.5|z|$.

Comment: @Wojowu Silly of me to not have spent an additional minute to think of that.  Good catch.